# Problema al conectar con un socket UDP

Tags: c#, socket

Tengo una aplicación cliente/servidor que transmite datos por un socket UDP y todo funciona correctamente si ejecuto el cliente y el servidor en el mismo equipo. En el momento que una de las partes está bajo otra IP me da una excepción en la aplicación del cliente, incluso si ambos equipos están en la misma LAN y son accesibles:

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: 'La dirección solicitada no es válida en este contexto'
```

He probado a cambiar el puerto y a poner un `Thread.Sleep()` con varios segundos por si resultaba que el socket del servidor aun no se había creado pero no ha dado resultado.

También he probado a poner en el cliente con `IPAddress.Any` o intercambiar los código del cliente con el servidor, esto hace que no salte la excepción pero entonces el cliente no recibe ningún paquete del servidor. Estoy ahora mismo en un punto muerto y no se me ocurre nada más, estoy casi seguro que es un error relacionado con las IPs pero no soy capaz de solucionarlo.

```
//IP del cliente: 192.168.1.120
//IP del servidor: 192.168.1.2

private void Client_Start(IPAddress ip, int port) // IP = 192.168.1.2      port = 8554
{
    clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
    clientSocket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
    clientSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(IP), port)); // Lugar de la excepción
}

private void Server_Start(IPAddress ip, int port) // IP = 192.168.1.120    port = 8554
{
    serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
    serverSocket.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(IP), port));
}
```

**Edit:** He solucionado la excepción, era que estaba asignando en el cliente la IP del servidor por error. De todas formas no recibo los paquetes del servidor si no se encuentran ambas partes en el mismo equipo.

Comment: Estos equipos se conectan con un solo router? Si son dos, están ambos repartiendo direcciones ip? Si usan  el mismo routee' está con. Ssids separados para 2.4 y 5g?

Comment: @ffflabs Están en el mismo router y con conexión cableada, me parece que es algún problema en el cortafuegos del cliente, estoy investigando para solucionar el problema.